# Are the helm and navigation console reversed on Klingon ships?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, the-voyage-home

On Starfleet ships, Sulu sits at the helm on the port side of the bridge, and Chekov sits at the navigational console on the starboard side.

However, on the bridge of the Klingon bird of prey flown in *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*, Sulu now sits on the *starboard* side, and Chekov is on the *port* side.  (Interestingly, Uhura is in her usual spot.)

**Are the helm and navigational consoles of Klingon ships reversed from those of the Federation?**  Is it consistently portrayed this way throughout the franchise?

[image: Klingon bridge from ST:IV]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placement of duty stations on the bridge is not shown consistently even for just that individual bird of prey.  Take a look at what is going what on the Klingon bridge in these scenes from the previous film.

The first thing you may notice is that the layout of the bridge is entirely different between *Star Trek III:  The Search for Spock* and *Star Trek IV:  The Voyage Home*.  In addition to a distinctly different design styling, the layout of duty stations is different.  There are four crew stations in front of the captain's chair (following the  circular shape of the bridge as it appears *Star Trek III*) and two more farther back, on the port and starboard sides of the bridge.  The ship's two junior Klingon officers, Maltz the first officer and Torg the second officer, are located at these stations.  Maltz, on the starboard side appears to have the navigation station (as he gives position readings) and Torg, at port, has sensors.  The other duty station we can identify with certainty is the gunner, who is seated second from the port side among the four front stations.